# In asp.net-mvc, how can I replicate creating this using javascript instead of serverside C#?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, asp.net-mvc, stringify

I have an asp.net-mvc page and in my javascript in my view, I have this code which works perfect:

MyView.aspx

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     var apps = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Apps) %>;
     SetupApplications(apps);

  </script>
```

(Apps is a array of strings).

I now need to change this to be called from an ajax method.  I tried a few things but neither seemed to work.  I am passing back a string array from server side controller action like this:

```
     return Json(new { 
            Apps = GetAppsStringArray()
        });
```

and on the client side javascript callback I call the same method:

```
  $.post("/MyController/MyAction", function (data) {
        SetupApplications(JSON.stringify(data.Apps) }
    , "json");
```

Do you see anything flawed in why these wouldn't be equivalent?

Comment: "but neither seemed to work" is not a good explanation of a problem. Consider using debugger (most browsers have at least one built in) and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a JSON string from the object that was created by parsing the JSON string that you get in the response. As the `SetupApplications` function doesn't take a JSON string in the first version of the code, it shouldn't do that in the second either. Just pass the object to the function without turning it into JSON again:

```
$.post("/MyController/MyAction", function (data) {
  SetupApplications(data.Apps);
}, "json");
```